# Переопределить функцию

Tags: функции, wp-plugin

Есть плагин на WP (без классов, просто функции, без фильтров), он обновляется. Одну из функций надо переписать.

Какие есть идеи?

Comment: эм...я не могу понять, что Вы хотите услышать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Если функция висит на каком-то хуке, то можно снять ее с хука и поставить свою

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'plugin_function', 20 );

add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_function', 20 );
```

2. Если функция стоит в конструкции

```
if (!function_exists('my_function')) {
   function my_function() {
   }
}
```

то можно эту функцию повторно определить в functions.php темы (он грузится раньше плагинов) и тогда плагин будет работать с Вашей функцией из темы